# Can't load Features.Diagnostics

Tags: azure, azure-communication-services

I'm creating a web client for joining Teams meetings with the ACS Calling SDK.
I'm having trouble loading the *diagnostics* API. Microsoft provides this page:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/concepts/voice-video-calling/call-diagnostics

You are supposed to get the diagnostics this way:
`const callDiagnostics = call.api(Features.Diagnostics);`

This does not work.

I am loading the Features like this:
`import { Features } from '@azure/communication-calling'`

A statement `console.log(Features)` shows only these four features:

- DominantSpeakers: (...)
- Recording: (...)
- Transcription: (...)
- Transfer: (...)

Where are the Diagnostics??

Answer (score 2):

## User Facing Diagnostics

For anyone, like me, looking now...

ATOW, using the [latest version of @azure/communication-calling SDK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/communication-calling/v/1.6.3), the [documented solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/concepts/voice-video-calling/user-facing-diagnostics#accessing-diagnostics), still doesn't work:

```
const callDiagnostics = call.api(Features.Diagnostics);
```

`call.api` is undefined.

### TL;DR

However, once the call is instantiated, this allows you to subscribe to changes:

```
const call = callAgent.join(/** your settings **/);

const userFacingDiagnostics = call.feature(Features.UserFacingDiagnostics);

userFacingDiagnostics.media.on("diagnosticChanged", (diagnosticInfo) => {
  console.log(diagnosticInfo);
});

userFacingDiagnostics.network.on("diagnosticChanged", (diagnosticInfo) => {
   console.log(diagnosticInfo);
});
```

This isn't documented in the latest version, but *is* under [this alpha version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/communication-calling/v/1.5.2-alpha.20220415.1).

Whether this will continue to work is anyone's guess ¯\*(ツ)*/¯

## Accessing Pre-Call APIs

Confusingly, [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/concepts/voice-video-calling/pre-call-diagnostics#accessing-pre-call-apis) *doesn't* currently work using the specified version, despite the docs saying it will...

`Features.PreCallDiagnostics` is undefined.

This is actually what I was looking for, but I can get what I want by setting up a test call asking for the latest values, like this:

```
const call = callAgent.join(/** your settings **/);

const userFacingDiagnostics = call.feature(Features.UserFacingDiagnostics);

console.log(userFacingDiagnostics.media.getLatest())
console.log(userFacingDiagnostics.network.getLatest())
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Currently the [User Facing Diagnostics API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/concepts/voice-video-calling/call-diagnostics) is only available in the Public Preview and npm beta packages right now. I confirmed this with a quick test comparing the 1.1.0 and beta packages.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following link:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/communication-services-web-calling-tutorial/

Features are imported from the @azure/communication-calling,
for example:

```
const {
   Features
} = require('@azure/communication-calling');
```